# Golang channel pair assignment in select statement

Tags: go

Is there a way to do a channel pair assignment in a select case statement?

Outside of a select statement you can do something like the following, but it doesn't seem to work in a select case statement.

```
var c1 = make(chan int)
var c2 = make(chan int)
a,b := <- c1, <- c2
```

Why can't I do the following:

```
var c1 = make(chan int)
var c2 = make(chan int)

go func () {
    c1 <- 11111
}()

go func () {
    c2 <- 22222
}()

select {
case a,b := <- c1, <- c2:
    fmt.Println(a,b)
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong OR is this just not possible without forming a new aggregator channel?

The end goal is to easily wait for both channels to be ready.

Comment: No, it's not possible to select on 2 channels simultaneously: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements

Comment: I mean, what would the semantics of that type of select be anyway?  Would the case only be valid if _both_ channels are ready for a receive?  Seems like a design problem if that's what you're going for (or you need a fan-in).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.
Yeah. I was going for a sorta fan-in layout. I conclude that you cannot select on two channels simultaneously(conditioned on both being ready to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just not possible.

If you need to wait for both channels to be ready, you may use:

```
a := <-c1
b := <-c2
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OZ7Dr5SyeO)

---

In some use cases, you may use this:

```
select {
case a, ok1 := <-c1:
    b, ok2 := <-c2
    if ok1 && ok2 {
        fmt.Println("C1 and C2 both Ready:", a, b)
    }
}
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RDeT0du92B)